# Over-extrusion on curved surfaces?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-cr-10

I am having issues with my Creality CR-10 S5 running Cura 4.6.1. If I use the Ender-3 G-code, it prints perfect. If I do the exact same print with S5 printer selected, I get garbage prints with lots of burps.[image: Ender-3 on left / CR-10 S5 on right]

Comment: Have you calibrated your E steps?

Comment: If both files are printed on the same machine, then incorrect E steps would affect both prints (unless there is `M92` call in one of the files, fixing or spoiling the print, e.g. in the start G-code). The one at right looks like it has fuzzy skin enabled. I added an answer with troubleshooting hints, maybe someone can make use of them.

Comment: could be diffeerend print speed settings...

Answer (score 2):

Comparing printing results of some G-code with results of samples generated by a slicer with many unknown settings is too superficial. You need to do more insight.

You can learn by comparing G-code files, but I suppose it would not be sufficient to have successful prints. You can also learn from tutorials on how to properly configure slicer. Understanding [slicer setting](https://all3dp.com/1/cura-tutorial-software-slicer-cura-3d/), [common printing issues](https://cults3d.com/en/blog/articles/identify-correct-3D-printing-problems-defaults), [physics of plascic](https://toms3d.org/2018/02/02/things-know-filaments/) and [printing](https://manual.slic3r.org/advanced/flow-math) is very helpful for troubleshooting.

Between files there are number of parameters which could be different, including:

- slicer software, its approach (algorithms) and settings - *most probably it was Cura in both cases, but many settings could be different - if you have both profiles, then you may comare them setting by setting (thoguh it is not easy in Cura, but see next)*
- notes in comments (in opening and ending sections of file) - *Cura is printing lot of profile settings at the end of the file*
- G-code initialization commands in opening section of file - *there may be key changes to printer configuration, and also information about following *
- temperature settings - *you can read it from G-code or from LCD, when print is started*
- retraction and speed settings - *you can read it from E move commands*
- layer height - *you can read it from Z move commands*
- total use of filament per print - *use analyzer, see below*
- printhead movements (including experimental Fuzzy Skin) - *check settings, and use visualisation in Cura just after slicing*

Machine profile ("S5 printer selected") in Cura intoduces subset of default settings. In CR-10 S5 profile created by Creality many settings may be very different than in profile for Ender 3. And still author of original G-code file could update many of these settings before slicing.

You can compare two G-code files for the same shape in [GCode Analyzer](https://gcode.ws/). For easier work you may open two or more analysers in separate browser tabs. There are many useful information calculated from G-code - about *Model* (like "Total filament used") and and *Layer* (like "Retract speeds"). Layers may be changed in *2D* view with right scroolbar (clik the square scroll indicator and use Up and Down arrows on keyboard).